# Need clear explanation about medias/files/attchments

Tags: post-thumbnails, attachments, media-library

During an import, I need to add images and linked to a custom post using WPML like :

1. post 1 in french

   1.1 picture foo.jpg (visible in library and attached to this post and add as featured image )

   1.2 picture bar.jpg (visible in library and attched to this post)
2. post 1 in english

   2.1 picture foo.jpg (visible in library and attched to this post and add as featured image)

   2.2 picture bar.jpg (visible in library and attched to this post)
3. post 2 in french...

Sometimes I´ve got these weird behaviours :

- Featured image visible in post but not visible in library
- Others images found but not visible in library
- and others kind of bugs about this

So, I would like to get an explanation about how Wordpress works to get images in library and be attached and as featured for others custom post type.
What happens in the database ?

If you have a good tutorial or explanation on the Web, please share me the link.

Comment: Note that any explanation will assume vanilla WP, but by adding WPML you've introduced unknown variables that require WPML specific expertise. It won't be possible to answer your question in a way that fills the gaps in knowledge you have as a result, and it won't explain the problems you're having as they're not something that happens in standard WordPress. E.g. WP has no concept of languages. You will need to contact WPML support or consult with other WPML users on a WPML group/forum/event

Answer (score 4):

Attachments in WP are stored as posts of type `attachment` which reference files physically stored in the uploads folder. This is why if you FTP a file into the uploads folder it doesn't appear in the media library.

This means the media library is a post archive, much like other post archives in the admin and frontend. Specifically listing posts of type `attachment`. The media library is not a folder/filesystem browser.

This also means that:

- badly written `pre_get_posts` filters can influence it, always check if it's the main query and if it's the frontend
- `attachments` have post IDs
- `attachments` can have post meta, comments, taxonomies
- `attachments` like other posts have URLs and theme templates out of the box

Featured images are just a post meta key whose value is an attachment ID. They are nothing special beyond that other than having a special UI in the post editor. The media library modal doesn't do anything special in this regard though.

It's also poor practice to store URLs of uploaded items, instead using the ID of the attachment post is best practice.

By default, WP will show only posts of type `post` in archives, this is why you don't see attachments or other internal post types such as navigation menu items listed. You could change that with `pre_get_posts`.

## How are Featured Images/ Post Thumbnails Stored?

It's an attachment ID number saved as a post meta/custom field on a post named `_thumbnail_id`. That ID can be any number, though it makes sense for it to be a post of type `attachment`. That's it, it's just a post meta key value just like any other.

## What makes an Attachment "Attached"?

The `post_parent` parameter in the post table. It works exactly the same way as parent and child pages. It's all the same at the database level, there is no special sauce or fields for this.

However, it carries far less weight than pages. Being *attached* might change some minor UI in WP Admin, but it's inconsequential.

An attachments attached status has no effect on queries unless explicitly queried for. This isn't something the media library normally does unless a plugin modifies it.

An attachment

- can be used in a post it's not attached to
- can be attached to a post and never used
- can be used in posts and be unattached

For the vast majority of situations, you can ignore the `post_parent` relationship. This value is normally used by people wanting to show a list of all the images in a post, or as a handy way to link back to the post once clicking on the attachments frontend page.

As a result, it's mainly convention. Attachment IDs can be referenced everywhere, and **there is no special treatment from the database** for attached attachments that changes their behaviour

### Can I Attach to Multiple Posts?

No. The `post_parent` column of the posts table contains a single number value, not an array or list.

Since a post can only have a single parent, `attachment` posts can only be attached to a single parent. You cannot attach an `attachment` to more than one post at the database level, just like you can't have a page with multiple direct parents.

### How Do You Unattach An Attachment In The Database?

Unattached `attachment` posts have a `post_parent` of `0`. This is true of all top level posts and pages

## What About CPT's?

Custom post types are just post types. The only difference in the database is the `post_type` column in the posts table. There is no difference in their behaviour or logic at the database level, and none that impact attachments.

The only thing that comes close is wether the CPT supports the featured image. All this does is toggle the UI. If you manually add the post meta it still works.

The main practical differences to CPT's are all defined in PHP not the database, e.g. `post` and `page` have `builtin` set to `true` but they're all defined at runtime in PHP. The behaviour differences are all defined in PHP too. In the database, it's a level playing field.

## What About Languages?

WordPress has no multilingual support, so this does not factor in. Posts are non-lingual in that sense.

If you have installed a plugin that adds languages though, then **you will need to consult that plugins documentation or contact their support routes** for how it interacts with attachments, or even if it interacts with them.

Comment: Is there a link between `post_parent` and to be attached ? Because I found an attachment post with `post_parent=0`

Comment: How in the database is written the link between the attachment and my custom post ?

Comment: `post_parent` is how it knows what it's attached to, but it's not necessary for an attachment to be used. Multiple posts can use the same attachment as their featured image, attachments can have no post parent, or be attached to a post that doesn't use that attachment. The concept carries very little weight if any

Comment: Also, a CPT is just a post with a different value in the `post_type` column, there are no special database considerations for CPT's or custom taxonomies

Comment: Note that I've stated those in my answer already. i'll make this clearer but that just means adding headings. Re-read my answer carefully, it's all in there

Comment: So, maybe I got errors because I try to use the Wordpress attach way for each post (french and english) and post_parent can be only one. So if I use this way, I should attach to the post with default language or find the WPML way.

Comment: You'll need to speak with people familiar with WPML, this site isn't the place to ask for WPML help, as a 3rd party plugin WPML is offtopic here and not in this stacks scope. I can only speak to what happens in standard WordPress